# Problema con firebase init y deploy, "no deploy targets found"

Tags: firebase, angularjs-2.0, deployment

Tengo un problema al querer subir mi proyecto a firebase, al poner firebase init
y luego de seleccionar hosting y la base de datos que también esta en firebase me aparece :

```js
i  .firebaserc already has a default project, skipping

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

+  Firebase initialization complete!
```

y al dar firebase deploy me aparece el siguiente error

```js
Error: No deploy targets found. Valid targets: database,storage,functions,hosting
```

una vez aparece el error se elimina el firebase-debug.log

mi firebase.json queda vacio solo con {}
y mi .firebaserc queda con :

```js
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "colefuente"
  }
}
```

mi versión de firebase-tools es

$ npm firebase-tools -v
4.1.2

no se que mas hacer :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione revizando la guia para hacerlo de firebase, eliminé los campos de database-rules.json y la del storage que no iba  usar, solo deje la del hosting y funcionó :3

```js
{

  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "database-rules.json",
      "storage.rules"
    ]
  }
}
```